# Hide scrollbar created by iscrollview in JQuery mobile page slide transition

Tags: jquery-mobile, iscrollview

Is there a way to hide scrollbar created by iscrollview when a JQuery mobile page transition is taking place.

Comment: sure. listen to pagebeforechange

Comment: How to manually hide the scrollbar programmatically?